# Why there are different ensembl exon IDs for exactly same chromosome coordinates

Tags: bioinformatics, dna-sequence, genome

I  downloaded the exon coordinates of the human genome (hg38) and ensembl version 87 from the [biomart](http://dec2016.archive.ensembl.org/biomart). I extracted following information.

```
Chromosome/scaffold name Exon ID Exon Chr Start (bp) Exon Chr End (bp) Strand
```

for the same chromosome name and exon start and end coordinates, there are multiple Exon IDs. I am unable to understand why?

For example, on chromosome 5 positive strand (+), at the genomic coordinates (start position 141505393 and stop position 141505481), there are more than 1 exon IDs (ENSE00003461101 and ENSE00003463136 and ENSE00003473630 and ENSE3474096 and ENSE00003484284).

In other words, all these different exon IDs are exactly the same exons with same start and stop coordinates on the same chromosome and on the same strand.

How is that possible? Am I missing something?

Comment: Is https://www.biostars.org/p/144148/ any help in answering this question? (The answer there suggests it's because they have different sources.)

Comment: they do not belong to the same transcript.

Comment: @Pierre I understand that they belong to different transcripts. Does this mean that even with exactly same coordinates and location, the exon will have different unique ID based on which transcript it belongs to? In other words, does it means that the only important thing to consider is chr number, strand and coordinates while Exon ID will not be important.